# Is there any specific order for the synchronization blocks at the receiver?

Tags: digital-communications, synchronization

I am working on frequency, time and phase synchronization at the receiver, and although there is a consensus that coarse frequency synchronization is the first block in the chain, I am confused about the order of other blocks, especially between frame synchronization and symbol time synchronization. In this [link](https://pysdr.org/content/sync.html#:%7E:text=Frequency%20synchronization%20is%20usually%20broken,sync%2C%20while%20fine%20happens%20after.) the order of blocks are

- Coarse Frequency Synchronization
- Symbol Time Synchronization
- Fine Frequency Synchronization
- Demodulation(?)
- Frame Synchronization

I saw other order like

- Coarse Frequency Synchronization
- Frame Synchronization
- Symbol Time Synchronization
- Fine Frequency Synchronization
- PLL
- Demodulation(?)

Is there something I need to take into account when changing the order of the blocks?

Answer (score 1):

I'm on the run, but can give a short factual, if not very illustrative answer:

The order depends on the kind of signal, and on the methods you choose to synchronize. There's no "one common order".